# googletest - automatically print out which EXPECT statement failed

Tags: c++, googletest

If a test has more than one `EXPECT_*` statement

```
TEST_F(TestClass, ServerTest) {
    // Start server
    server_.start();
    usleep(200000);
    EXPECT_TRUE(server_.running());

    server_.stop();
    EXPECT_FALSE(server_.running());
}
```

how do I configure google-test to output which of the `EXPECT_*` actually failed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the insertion operator `<<` to print a message in case the assert/expect fails:

```
EXPECTED_TRUE(...) << "... turned out to be false";
```

---

On an unrelated note, `server_.start()` seems like a call one would make in a test fixture constructor. If you need to assert some condition, you can put it in the in test fixture `SetUp` and `TearDown` [methods](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests-same-data-multiple-tests).